# How to update a record using LINQ LAMBDA in my ASP.NET MVC 5 Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to entity framework and LINQ. I am stuck at an issue where I need to firstly check if the record already exists, if it exists then I need to update the record with column **RESUMEID** accordingly. If not then I need to add the record. I am able to add successfully but I don't know how to update the record in LINQ.

Below is my attempt:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(ReferralViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var candidateId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
         // I AM CONFUSED ABOUT BELOW STATEMENT
        var IsDupeReferral = _context.Referrals
       .Where(r => (r.CandidateId == candidateId)
      && (r.CompanyId == viewModel.CompanyId) && (r.SkillId == viewModel.SkillId))
      .Select(r=>r.ReferralId).SingleOrDefault();

        if(IsDupeReferral!=0)
        {
          //IF I FIND DUPE REFERRAL RECORD I WANT TO UPDATE SOME OF THE VALUES IN THAT
                  _context.Referrals.Where(r => r.ReferralId == IsDupeReferral).
             AND UPDATE r.resumeId with viewModel.ResumeId // How to do this?
             // NOT SURE ABOUT BELOW LINE EITHER
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
           // BELOW CODE IS WORKING FINE
            var referral = new Referral
            {
                ReferralName = viewModel.ReferralName,
                ResumeId = viewModel.ResumeId,
                CandidateId = candidateId,
                DegreeId = viewModel.DegreeId,
                CoverLetterId = viewModel.CoverLetterId,
                SkillId = viewModel.SkillId
            };

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.TempCompany))
            {
                var newCompany = new Company
                {
                    CompanyName = viewModel.TempCompany
                };
                newCompany.Referrals.Add(referral);
                _context.Companies.Add(newCompany); ;
            }
            else
            {
                referral.CompanyId = viewModel.CompanyId.Value;
                _context.Referrals.Add(referral);
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("ReferralCenter");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution

```
//IF I FIND DUPE REFERRAL RECORD I WANT TO UPDATE SOME OF THE VALUES IN THAT
var referral = _context.Referrals.FirstOrDefault(r => r.ReferralId == IsDupeReferral);
// AND UPDATE r.resumeId with viewModel.ResumeId
if (referral !=null) {
    referral.resumeId = viewModel.ResumeId; 
    _context.Entry(referral).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Actually, you don't need getting the IsDupeReferral and then request the record again. Try to combine your code as the following:

```
var referral = _context.Referrals
       .Where(r => (r.CandidateId == candidateId)
      && (r.CompanyId == viewModel.CompanyId) && (r.SkillId == viewModel.SkillId)).SingleOrDefault();

    if (referral !=null) {
        referral.resumeId = viewModel.ResumeId; 
        _context.Entry(referral).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    else {

     // add a new record 
    }
```

Comment: Sir, Is this necessary? `_context.Entry(referral).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: And below answer uses. FirstOrDefault. Can you kindly tell me which one shall I use. FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault?

Comment: Is EF not smart enough to know that I am modifying a row? Or do we need to set the row state explicitly?

Comment: SingleOrDefault will throw an error if there's more that 1 record in the result set. FirstOrDefault will return a first records or null if there's no records.

Comment: Most likely it will not work without setting the state explicitly, but it might depend on your version of EF and settings.If a records is tracked by the context, you don't need to set the state explicitly when modifying it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Referral referral = _context.Referrals.FirstOrDefault(r=> r.ReferralId = SomeId);
if(referral == null) // then referral does not exist - add it
{
    referral = new Referral{
                ReferralName = viewModel.ReferralName,
                ResumeId = viewModel.ResumeId,
                CandidateId = candidateId,
                DegreeId = viewModel.DegreeId,
                CoverLetterId = viewModel.CoverLetterId,
                SkillId = viewModel.SkillId
            };
    _context.Referrals.Add(referral);
}   
else  // referral already exists - update its values
{
    //make changes to referral
    referral.ReferralName = viewModel.ReferralName;
    referral.ResumeId = viewModel.ResumeId;
    referral.CandidateId = candidateId;
    referral.DegreeId = viewModel.DegreeId;
    referral.CoverLetterId = viewModel.CoverLetterId;
    referral.SkillId = viewModel.SkillId;

}
_context.SaveChanges(); //no matter added or updated - save the changes
```

Comment: Sir, I want the exception to be thrown if more than one record matches. I mean If my application has to work correctly then ATMOST 1 result from the referral  is possible. So ShallI use FirstorDefault or SingleOrDerfault?

Comment: Either the result will be one or zero. What shall I use "SingleorDefault" Or "FirstOrDefault"

Comment: I just now read about both in wiki and it says that no exception will be thrown if I get multiple records from "FirstOrDefault". Can you kindly guide me

Comment: @Unbreakable in here both has the same use, it is only to see if any records matches while getting the matching record (if we didn't want to update and didn't need matching record we could simply use `.Any`)

Comment: But by mistake if I get two matching records (some ghost data) then what happens in that case. I will never get an exception right (if I use firstordefault)?

Comment: why would you have more than one match if you never allow adding when there is a match

Comment: Yes your are right. I am a beginner so just trying to understand. Thanks a ton

Comment: I will try to implement this answer and will ACCEPT/COMMENT on your answer accordingly.